# add multiple listview in one activity

Tags: android, listview, android-activity

I want to add multiple listview like one app for twitter for android : [link](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.chriswstewart.twitter&feature=search_result)
But eveytime i try to add multiple listview in the XML and populate it there is just the first one that appear . Do you have an explanation ?

Comment: You probably have them in a `LinearLayout` with height set to fill the parent. Try giving them 0 height and 1 weight each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical">

<ListView android:id="@+id/list1"
      android:layout_height="0"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1" />

<ListView android:id="@+id/list2"
      android:layout_height="0"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

You can put any number of listviews as long as you define the height of each to be 0 and weight 1. Hope that helps. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how that twitter app works, but this can be easily done using fragments. Subclass `ListFragment` and then add as many fragments as you want in your Activity.