# Android, How to split ListView items into three parts?

Tags: android, listview, split

In my activity, i have three lists and each list has three items. After testing this way (please see: [Android, How to add ScrollView into screen which has some list items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10496804/android-how-to-add-scrollview-into-screen-which-has-some-list-items/10497011#10497011)), i found that its impossible to scroll screen while you have some lists in an activity. Also, I found this answer ([add multiple listview in one activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6404413/add-multiple-listview-in-one-activity?answertab=votes#tab-top)) which divided the screen into three segments therefore, i didn't have enough space to show all items and screen was not scrollable as well.

one silly solution is to create xml for each item and put it in xml layout of activity. Although it works but i have to copy/paste so many lines of code.

Better way is using adapter, so, in my next try, i can add the result of two other lists into my first list and then send the result to adapter class. Therefore, adapter will show all items in the list. Although, it solves my problem abut scrolling of screen (at this time scroll of screen = scroll of list), but I need to have header at top of each three items.

Is it possible to tell adapter to add for example header.xml, after each three items of list?

Hope to explain clearly! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
/>
```

header.xml

```
<TextView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center" android:scrollbars="none"
style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle" />
```

Now The java File code Given below.

SectionedAdapter .java

```
package com.android.listview;

import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

abstract public class SectionedAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
abstract protected View getHeaderView(String caption, int index,
View convertView, ViewGroup parent);

private List
sections = new ArrayList
();
private static int TYPE_SECTION_HEADER = 1;

public SectionedAdapter() {
super();
}

public void addSection(String caption, Adapter adapter) {
sections.add(new Section(caption, adapter));
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
for (Section section : this.sections) {
if (position == 0) {
return (section);
}

int size = section.adapter.getCount() + 1;

if (position <>
return (section.adapter.getItem(position - 1));
}

position -= size;
}

return (null);
}

public int getCount() {
int total = 0;

for (Section section : this.sections) {
total += section.adapter.getCount() + 1; // add one for header
}

return (total);
}

public int getViewTypeCount() {
int total = 1; // one for the header, plus those from sections

for (Section section : this.sections) {
total += section.adapter.getViewTypeCount();
}

return (total);
}

public int getItemViewType(int position) {
int typeOffset = TYPE_SECTION_HEADER + 1; // start counting from here

for (Section section : this.sections) {
if (position == 0) {
return (TYPE_SECTION_HEADER);
}

int size = section.adapter.getCount() + 1;

if (position <>
return (typeOffset + section.adapter
.getItemViewType(position - 1));
}

position -= size;
typeOffset += section.adapter.getViewTypeCount();
}

return (-1);
}

public boolean areAllItemsSelectable() {
return (false);
}

public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
return (getItemViewType(position) != TYPE_SECTION_HEADER);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
int sectionIndex = 0;

for (Section section : this.sections) {
if (position == 0) {
return (getHeaderView(section.caption, sectionIndex,
convertView, parent));
}

int size = section.adapter.getCount() + 1;

if (position <>
return (section.adapter.getView(position - 1, convertView,
parent));
}

position -= size;
sectionIndex++;
}

return (null);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
return (position);
}

class Section {
String caption;
Adapter adapter;

Section(String caption, Adapter adapter) {
this.caption = caption;
this.adapter = adapter;
}
}
}
```

Selection.java

```
package com.commonsware.android.listview;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class SectionedDemo extends ListActivity {
private static String[] items = { "US", "UK", "CANADA", "JAPAN", "SINGAPORE",
"INDIA", "CHINA" };

private static String[] Sect = { "GOOGLE", "FACEBOOK","DELL" };

private static String[] Doc = { "FRONT", "TOP","BACK" };

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
super.onCreate(icicle);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

adapter.addSection("step 1", new ArrayAdapter(this,
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items));

adapter.addSection("Step 2", new ArrayAdapter(this,
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Sect));

adapter.addSection("Step 3", new ArrayAdapter(this,
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Doc));

setListAdapter(adapter);
}

SectionedAdapter adapter = new SectionedAdapter() {
protected View getHeaderView(String caption, int index,
View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
TextView result = (TextView) convertView;

if (convertView == null) {
result = (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
R.layout.header, null);
}

result.setText(caption);

return (result);
}
};
}
```

[LINK](http://blogingtutorials.blogspot.in/2010/11/android-listview-header-two-or-more-in.html)  [LINK](http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-sectioned-headers-in-listviews/)