# How to make a custom Listview with different row layout and section Headers in android

Tags: android, listview

I am totally a beginner in android development and want to make a ListView fully customized like this, but don't understand where to start. So a help would be a big push for me.

[image]

please add source code if u can. Thank You.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10509306/android-how-to-split-listview-items-into-three-parts

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at these tutorials 
http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/listview-with-section-header-in-android

http://www.sunilandroid.com/2013/08/section-header-listview-in-android.html